# Beads in the Ancient Indus Valley

Tags: ancient-history, indus-valley

I’m interested in the manufacture, sales and use of beads in the ancient Indus Valley, particularly during the mature Harappan Civilization.
Would beads have been manufactured predominantly by men or women at the time?
I’m referring primarily to Carnelian, Quartz and Stone beads, but I’d be happy to hear any information about any bead production at the time, or indeed broader jewellery production.

Were those beads sold in an ancient version of a jewellery store or would they have been sold on the streets?
Would the beads have been sold by men or women?
Were these sorts of beads and other jewellery worn mostly by women or would men have also worn them?
Were the beads mostly for jewellery or were they used as currency etc?

Comment: Welcome to [history.se]! Please take the time to read the [tour] and [help/on-topic]. You ask several questions, while all tangentially related, some may be way too broad, possibly opening your question to Votes To Close.

Comment: @GCCampbell I asked several questions here because they are all very related & as a new user,asking 5 separate questions all at once,known as 'flooding',would be a much worse offence.I've kept the questions somewhat broad because this is a beta site with very few(less than 9,000)users, so even with this broadening of scope its still unlikely that these questions will get anything more than cursory views (only 23 after 24 hours) & if I'm lucky a non-specific answer.With that said,if you'd prefer that I split this up into 5 separate questions then let me know here & I'll be happy to do just that